# Why <ol><li>a</li><li>b</li></ol> remain unnumbered?

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML. I have built several webpages. All the pages are using the same css. But in a page I have `ol` where I want to force them to be numbered

**HTML:**

```
<ol><li>a</li><li>b</li></ol>
```

The above code remain unnumbered? Can I do something to force them numbered?

Comment: you will have to reproduce the issue in a fiddle or so for us to debug..

Comment: By default it should work as such..see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/yrs14cb7/)

Comment: better description about question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some style on the page is setting the `list-style-type` property. You can override it in a stylesheet, or style the ol tag directly:

```html
<ol style="list-style-type:circle"><li>list-style-type</li><li>circle</li></ol>
<ol style="list-style-type:decimal"><li>list-style-type</li><li>decimal</li></ol>
```

Comment: I do not know why. I copy your code to fiddle. It works well. And if I copy them to my html. It stayed unnumbered.

Comment: This is the original code.    `<ol style="list-style-type:decimal">
<li >Name<br>
    <i>Thesis</i> 
 <br></li>&nbsp;
</ol>`

Comment: There's only one `<li>` in there, so there's just one number... Or are you not even seeing a `1`?

Comment: @TerryQiao remove the `&nbsp;`, it comes after the closing `li` therefore making the markup invalid

Answer (score 0):

You can try here:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp

Set the `list-type` CSS property.

Answer (score -1):

```
ol {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

Comment: A downvote for the correct answer?  You guys are pros!